# Process less file to css with webpack in Asp.net core application

Tags: css, asp.net, webpack, less

I am trying to process a less file with webpack to a css file, but it is not processed.
Here is where I say to webpack to process less files:

```
var isDevBuild = process.argv.indexOf('--env.prod') < 0;
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
var merge = require('webpack-merge');
var allFilenamesExceptJavaScript = /\.(?!js(\?|$))([^.]+(\?|$))/;
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

var sharedConfig = {
resolve: { extensions: [ '', '.js', '.ts' ] },
output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: '/dist/' 
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        { test: /\.ts$/, include: /ClientApp/, loader: 'ts', query: { 
silent: true } },
        { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw' },
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'to-string!css' },
        { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|ttf|woff)$/, loader: 'url', query: 
{ limit: 25000 } },
        { test: /\.less$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", 
"css-loader!less-loader")}
    ]
}
};
```

Here is the location of my less file:
[Location less file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lb0U3.png)

And in package.json I have the following:

```
"webpack": "^1.12.14",
"webpack-externals-plugin": "^1.0.0",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0",
"webpack-merge": "^0.14.1",
"zone.js": "^0.6.21",
"extract-text-plus-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0",
"less-loader": "^4.0.3"
```